# Convert UTC based on a separate time zone column - Postgres

Tags: postgresql, datetime, timezone

I have a table which has:

- Source date column
- Source timestamp (30 minute interval, a string)
- The datetime UTC timestamptz column
- The 'reporting' time zone (how the time zone should be displayed eventually)

  ```
  date      interval     datetime_utc     time_zone
  ```

  2018-05-11    22:30     2018-05-10 03:30:00  America/New_York

Is there an efficient way to convert the datetime_utc column to the time zone indicated in the same row within a query or a view? I was able to do this using Python, but I would like to know how to do it directly in my query.

This seems to work - I am able to refer to the column name and it converts it accurately based on the value found in that row.

```
 (interval_timestamp_utc :: TIMESTAMPTZ AT TIME ZONE time_zone) :: DATE AS "Reporting Date",

 to_char((interval_timestamp_utc :: TIMESTAMPTZ AT TIME ZONE time_zone), 'HH24:MI') AS "Reporting Interval",
```

Comment: `select '2018-05-10 03:30:00'::timestamp at time zone 'America/New_York';` ? Look also `pg_catalog.pg_timezone_abbrevs` and `pg_catalog.pg_timezone_names` tables.

Comment: Each row has a different time zone though - I am not selecting a specific row. I am querying a full calendar day which has about 1 - 2 million rows and I am converting the source time zone to a 'display' time zone used for visualizations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `AT TIME ZONE` construct should be what you're looking for. In your case, `SELECT TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE datetime_utc AT TIME ZONE time_zone` should give you the timestamp rendered without an offset for that specific time zone.

See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT for more details.

Comment: Hi - just wanted to make sure that this would still work if each row has a different time zone. There are about 20+ unique ones right now.

Comment: This seems to work and it is WAY shorter than my CASE WHEN statement with 20+ entries, thanks!